# Unity 3D is Layout Errors On a fresh install

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]Unity 3d doesnt work, when I try to open my project it says that This can happen if layout contains custom windows and there are compile errors in the project. I tried reinstalling OpenGL and something that I found on the internet but  didn't work. The error window says that Revert Factory Settings but same thing happens after it too my Unity version is 2020.1.0a My OS is Ubuntu and I gave all the permissions to some folders. Didn't work And all this happened after a fresh install

Comment: Provide a screenshot or paste the whole error log :D

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using an **ALPHA VERSION** ? In doubt stick to the latest stable builds `2019.2.6` or even `2019.1.14`. Since `2019.2` the entire GUI of the editor was reworked and might not be completely fixed yet .. even less for Ubuntu

Comment: I put a screenshot.

Comment: did you try `LoadDefaultLayout`?

Comment: How to try it? Did you mean the button, if you meaned it I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unity 2020.1.0a3](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/alpha/2020.1.0a3) is an **ALPHA VERSION**!

As any alpha version it is **not stable for production** and can be expected to be full of bugs and unexpected behavior.

Search through the `Known Issues in 2020.1.0a3` maybe your problem is already listed there.

---

In general **do not touch** alpha or beta versions unless you want to checkout a new added feature and test it.

For anything else stick to the **stable** releases like [`2019.1.14f1`](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/whats-new/2019.1.14) or [2019.2.6f1](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/whats-new/2019.2.6)

On the last letter you can see their state:

- `a` = Alpha
- `b` = Beta
- `f` = Release

---

Not sure if these are related but [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/failed-to-load-window-layout.241450/) and [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/757942/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-load-window-layout.html) also others had this problem already in early version so maybe one of their hot-fixes work for you as well.

Comment: This is not a fix can you is there anyway to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur in released versions.

To resolve this problem:

1. Go to this directory:

> C:\Users{YOUR_USER}\AppData\Roaming\Unity\Editor-5.x\Preferences\Layouts\default

2. Open Default.wlt file with Notepad or any text editor and copy all its contents.
3. Go to your unity project directory like this:

> {YOUR_UNITY_PROJECT}\Library

4. Open CurrentLayout-default.dwlt file with Notepad or any text editor and delete all its contents then paste the contents of Default.wlt that you copied in step 2
5. If these files exist in Library delete them:

> CurrentMaximizeLayout.dwlt

> CurrentLayout.dwlt

6. Stop the Unity Hub service by a click the system tray and right-click on Unity Hub icon then select Quit Unity Hub.
7. Run your project again.